# alert dialog size varies based on list view

Tags: android

I have created a alert dialog in oncreate dialog method of dialog fragment. I am populating the alert dialog with array adapter. My problem is the alert dialog size varies depending on the text in the adapter. I want the alert dialog to be fixed in default size. pls help.

Answer (score 0):

```
place the textview in scrollview with fixed height.
they are two methods to do that
1)by using the ScrollView


<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res /android">
<ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
 <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Venkata Reddy,"
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

> 2 method

```
<TextView
    android:text="Single-line text view that scrolls automatically if the text is too long to fit in the widget" 
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

use any one of the method...